# Text is long and move content to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a javascript what change text every 5 seconds. When i add a long text it move text to bottom, when te text is shorter it move all back. Why is that ? 
Javascript:

```js
var text = ["Piedāvājam visdažādākās spēles un lietotnes ar VR HTC brillēm, kas ir piemērotas jebkuram vecumam, sākot no 10 gadiem.", "Dzimšanas diena, vārda diena, vecpuišu vai vecmeitu ballīte vai kādi citi svētki VR Room ir ideāls risinājums, kur jautri pavadīt laiku kompānijai līdz 10 cilvēkiem. Ir iespējams uzklāt galdu saviem viesiem.", "Pusotras stundas seanss uz kompāniju līdz 10 cilvēkiem tikai pa 50 EUR."];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
setInterval(change, 5000);
   
function change() {
  elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
  $('#header').fadeIn(1000);
  counter++;
  if (counter >= text.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
    
function changeBackgroundSmoothly() {
  $('#header').fadeOut(1000, changeBg); //this is new, will fade out smoothly
}
    
setInterval(changeBackgroundSmoothly,5000);
```

```css
#header {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("../../images/header.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7.5em 0 2em 0;
    cursor: default;
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}
    
#header:before {
 content: '';
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 100%;
}
    
#header .inner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 50;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
      
#header header {
    display: inline-block;
}
    
#header header > p {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    margin: 0;
    text-overflow: ellipsis
}
    
#header h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3em;
    float: left;
    line-height: 2em;
}
#header header img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Header -->
  
   <div id="header"  >
   <div id="sliderB" ><img style="width:100%;height:100%;"  id='myimage' /></div>
   

    <!-- Inner -->
     <div class="inner">
      <header>
       
       <h1><a  id="logo" >VR Room</a></h1>
       
       <p id="changeText" > Pirmā Latvijā virtuālās realitātes istaba – “VR room”. Tu pat nevari iedomāties savu reākciju!</p>
       
      </header>
      <footer>
       <a href="#banner" class="button circled scrolly">Start</a>
      </footer>
     </div>
```

When it change text to the long sentence it takes all logo h1 text down in dividers bottom. Maybe there is something what can do better in my situation ? 
 How to fix this thing and why it wont work ? Sorry for bad language, not my native.

Comment: Google Translate, please help:
Es nesaprotu ļoti labi ... Vai jūs varat paskaidrot skaidrāk, ko jūs cenšaties sasniegt?

Comment: What is the `id="header"` element referenced in the JS and CSS and not shown in the HTML?

Comment: I update the HTML

Comment: I want to make that i can insert long texts in the js and it the long text will not break page desing, like it is now

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle...](https://jsfiddle.net/h8aorton/) I'm still not quite sure what you mean by "not break page design".

Comment: In my page, when  not so long text is showed throw JS it is in right palce, but when JS change to next  text in array what is very big, it change text positions and move the text to pages bottom, and when the short text comes again it change position back

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing closing div tag on your markup. Try to format your markup better; then it's much easier to see what's going on.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Header -->
<div id="header">
  <div id="sliderB">
    <img style="width:100%;height:100%;" id='myimage' />
  </div>


  <!-- Inner -->
  <div class="inner">
    <header>

      <h1><a id="logo">VR Room</a></h1>

      <p id="changeText">Pirmā Latvijā virtuālās realitātes istaba – “VR room”. Tu pat nevari iedomāties savu reākciju!</p>

    </header>

    <footer>
      <a href="#banner" class="button circled scrolly">Start</a>
    </footer>

  </div>
</div>
```

However, to answer your question: the text is sometimes wrapping underneath your h1 on narrower screens when it gets longer because that's the way HTML elements take up space. If you want to keep them divided in columns, your markup or your styles need to change.